# Display postgis data with qgis 2.2

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a problem with some shapefile, PolygonZ type, I have imported with "shp2pgsql-gui".

This is the output (note 'coord_dimension' value):

> ```
> mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=1, shape=1, srid=3003 
> Shapefile type: PolygonZ PostGIS type: MULTIPOLYGON[4] Shapefile
> import completed.
> ```

From this point of view it seems a data issue but I must say also that I'm able to display the same data with Qgis 1.8 (build from source).

So what could be the cause of this behavior?

PS:using Qgis 2.2 and Postgis 2.0.3 from UbuntuGIS repository on Linux Mint Maya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were expected to obtain a bi-dimensional multipolygon, but this isn't always true. As well, your imported data could have three or four dimensions, if your data looks to have this topology.

If this isn't the result you a looking for, you could repeat the import, by checking the `Generate simple geometries instead of Multi geometries` in "shp2pgsql-gui".

If this does not satisfy you, then maybe it is better to use "shp2pgsql" from a command line, and to specify the `dimensionality` as you wish:

[image]

What really concerning me is the fact you are able to load the 4th dimensional PostGIS layer only from QGIS 1.8. Therefore, if you can't do this thing in QGIS 2.2, you should open a [bug ticket](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/index#bugs-features-and-issues.html).

Comment: A ticket has already been open a day ago. http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9748